# Download file with Finagle Http Client

Tags: scala, finagle

I'm trying to take a byte array from the remote file. I created `AsyncStream` but don't have any idea how to transform it into a proper byte array.

```
  val client: Service[http.Request, http.Response] =
    Http
      .client
      .withStreaming(enabled = true)
      .newService("www.scala-lang.org:80")

  val request = http.Request(http.Method.Get, "/docu/files/ScalaOverview.pdf")
  request.host = "scala-lang.org"
  val response: Future[http.Response] = client(request)

  def fromReader(reader: Reader): AsyncStream[Buf] =
    AsyncStream.fromFuture(reader.read(Int.MaxValue)).flatMap {
      case None => AsyncStream.empty
      case Some(a) => a +:: fromReader(reader)
    }

  val result: Array[Byte] =
    Await.result(response.flatMap {
      case resp =>
        fromReader(resp.reader) ??? // what to do?
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `fromReader`, `AsyncStream` already has it. 
So, you can do something like this:

```
val result: Future[Array[Byte]] = response
  .flatMap { resp => 
    AsyncStream.fromReader(resp.reader)
      .foldLeft(Buf.Empty){ _ concat _ }
      .map(Buf.ByteArray.Owned.extract)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scalaj` for downloading files.

```
import scalaj.http._

val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http("http://foo.com/search").param("q","monkeys").asString
```

See the documentation for different type of requests Get, Post etc.

https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http